# lstlisting code is blue instead of black - keywordstyle taking over?

Tags: colors, lstlisting

When using lstlisting and certain parameters, (most) code turns blue, even though it should only be keywords and identifiers, while the rest should have a black color. For good measure, the rest of text in document is black :-)

Preferably the keywords should also be bold as well, but I've found out that might be a font problem, but I can't figure out how to change lstlisting font without changing font for the whole document.

Thanks for your time!

```
\lstset{language={[Sharp]C},
basicstyle=\color{black}\ttfamily\scriptsize,
numbers=left,
numberstyle=\tiny,
numbersep=3pt,
tabsize=1,
extendedchars=true,
breaklines=true,
keepspaces=true,
showspaces=false,
showtabs=false,
xleftmargin=5pt,
framexleftmargin=5pt,
framexrightmargin=5pt,
framexbottommargin=4pt,

morecomment=[l]{//}, %use comment-line-style!
morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/}, %for multiline comments
showstringspaces=false,
commentstyle=\color{black},
keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
identifierstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
backgroundcolor=\color{almostwhite},
}
```

Below is code sample in compiled PDF:

[image: Blue Code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if the problem has been solved but it seems your language C Sharp is not known is the predefined languages [here](https://latex.ugent.be/files/documenten/listings.pdf) p.12 tab 1.

You can create your own language by using  `lstdefinelanguage` see [here](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=29976) for an example of how it works